# Jump to Another Page After Generate Excel File in PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a form (form.php) for user to insert data, after user finish inserting data, form action will jump to formGenerateXLS.php (using POST method) for generate user data to XSL file. In the bottom of formGenerateXLS.php I put a javascript code to jump to dashboard (home.php) but it fail. The Excel file successfully generate but javascript code not working. How to work with that?

```
if(isset($_POST['issue_time'])){
   $product_desc = $_POST['product'];
   $filename_excel = date("Ymd_")."$product_desc";
   header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename_excel.xls");

   echo "<table border='1'>";
     echo "<tr>";
       echo "<th colspan='3' bgcolor='#1bf3b3'>New Ticket Request</th>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Name</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>User</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>"
}

echo "<script>window.location='home.php'</script>";
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is, but it seems like you are asking the server to send an excel file that opens with excel and some javascript that would run in the browser which doesn't make sense to me. Can you have the form submit to a new tab using `target="_blank"` so the excel file opens there and use an onsubmit event to change the location in the current tab?

Comment: @JasonB I mean I need to jump to another page after generating the XLS file. So the flow is : form.php -> formGenerateXLS.php (code already attach in description) -> home.php, but the problem is javascript window.location is not working after generate the XLS file

Comment: With the headers you are sending, the browser is not expecting to see and javascript. You are trying to send two types of information in the same stream but nothing you do after sending those headers should get executed as javascript. Does the XLS file open up in Excel on the client machine? If so, my first comment may do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Because echo does not execute the command, but simply writes it to the file.
In order to reposition a php file, use the header () function, for example `header ('location: home.php');`.